# Read XML with Oracle XMLTYPE: LPX-00210: expected '"' instead of '\'

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to read and XML in ORACLE using XMLTYPE.

I get the msg **LPX-00210: expected '"' instead of '\'** when using the the below xml.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<arrayofaccesstoken xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
<accesstoken>
<id>0</id>
<controller>fs</controller>
<view>fview</view>
<role>1000</role>
<rights>30</rights>
</accesstoken>
```

The code work perfectly fine when the first tow lines

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<arrayofaccesstoken xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
```

are omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to escape double quotes in an oracle string since all strings in oracle are enclosed by single quotes.

This XML should work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<arrayofaccesstoken xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <accesstoken>
        <id>0</id>
        <controller>fs</controller>
        <view>fview</view>
        <role>1000</role>
        <rights>30</rights>
    </accesstoken>
</arrayofaccesstoken>
```

Other things I fixed -

1. There was no closing token at the end.
2. There needs to be a space after you close the double quote for xmlns:xsi and before xmlns:xsd.

Comment: Getting this now LPX-00230: invalid character 10 (U+000A) found in a Name or Nmtoken

Comment: It probably doesn't support the line feed character as a line break. You can either remove all line breaks to make it work or do the changes I listed in your XML that worked for you earlier and you should be good.

Comment: What does your XML look like? The error says there is a line break inside an element token. Check that please.

Comment: You made my day.I was struggling to Interpret wat 10(u+000a) means.Its was a TYPO in the xml.